# compiling linux C++ in eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am trying to compile a c++ project.
I get an error that mutex.h is missing.
1) Where in linux in read hat all include are ?
2) Where do I include it in eclispe ?

Spasiva

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which type of mutex you are trying to use:

If it's the pthread mutex, then:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

If it's the C++11 mutex, then:

```
#include <mutex>
```

(you'll also need to compile with `-std=c++11`).